# ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler not catching my exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

In my Spring MVC application secured with Spring Security, I have to ways of loggin in: one is by recognizing a list of specific authorized IPs (which requires no user/password login) and one is by classic login. To this end, I build a custom authentication provider verifying whether the IP is authorized. In case it is not, I want it to redirect to an error page which informs the user.

I am throwing an exception (`org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException`) when this is the case, and I am trying to use `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler` to catch it and redirect to the proper page. The failure handler maps `InsufficientAuthenticationException` to that page, and also `BadCredentialsException` to another error page (used when performing classic user/pass login and the login is wrong).

I checked with logs that I am actually throwing the exception. However, the failure handler never catches it; instead, I always get the page that is intended for `BadCredentialsException`.
How can I make sure the exception I throw is catched by the failure handler?

Here's an extract of my security-context.xml:

```
<http
    auto-config="true"
    use-expressions="true">
    <form-login
        login-page="/pages/login.jsp"
        login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
</http>

<beans:bean
    id="customIPAddressAuthenticationProvider"
    class="ch.of.ow.security.CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider" />

<beans:bean
    id="authenticationFailureHandler"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler">
    <beans:property name="exceptionMappings">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop 
                key="org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException">
                /notValidIP
            </beans:prop> <!-- THIS IS THE PAGE I WANT -->
            <beans:prop 
                key="org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException">
                /pages/login.jsp?login_error=true
            </beans:prop>  <!-- THIS IS THE PAGE I GET INSTEAD -->
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>


 <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider ref="customIPAddressAuthenticationProvider" />
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='userDetailsService'>
    <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
    </authentication-provider>
 </authentication-manager>
```

And here is the relevant portion of CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider:

```
public class CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
        if (!authentication.getPrincipal().equals("") || !authentication.getCredentials().equals("")) {
            // if the user did provide a username/password, skip to the next
            // authentication provider, as he will want to log in with his
            // credentials instead of his IP
            return null;
        }
        WebAuthenticationDetails wad = null;
        String userIPAddress = null;
        boolean isAuthenticatedByIP = false;

        // Get the IP address of the user tyring to use the site
        wad = (WebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();
        userIPAddress = wad.getRemoteAddress();
        // Check if the user is authorized
        isAuthenticatedByIP = ipIsAuthorized(userIPAddress); //the ipIsAuthorized does its stuff well

        // Authenticated, the user's IP address is authorized
        if (isAuthenticatedByIP) {
            List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
            grantedAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
            Authentication result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("xxxxxxxxx", "yyyyyyyyy", grantedAuths);
            return result;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Going to throw InsufficientAuthenticationException");
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(userIPAddress);
        }
    }

}
```

Also I noticed that if I remove the second mapping of the failure handler, and I only leave it with:

```
            <beans:prop 
                key="org.springframework.security.authentication.InsufficientAuthenticationException">
                /notValidIP
            </beans:prop>
```

Then I see that if I try to access using a non-trusted IP, I get a `HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: Bad credentials` coming from `/j_spring_security_check`. So indeed that's the exception going out. Am I perhaps throwing my exception in the wrong place? Does throwing an exception in the authentication provider imply triggering a bad credentials exception higher in the chain?

Thanks in advance for any advice you may provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. If you have multiple authentication providers, Spring's `ProviderManager` takes care of iterating through them until it finds one that provides a valid authentication. 
If you throw an exception in one of the providers, as I did, the `ProviderManager` will catch it; however, unless the exception is an instance (or subclass) of either `AccountStatusException` or `InternalAuthenticationServiceException`, **it will just go on in the list of providers**. This is very clear by looking at the source code of `ProviderManager`.

In my case, this meant that as I threw the `InsufficientAuthenticationException` (which is neither a subclass of `AccountStatusException` nor `InternalAuthenticationServiceException`), the `ProviderManager` would catch it without stopping and move on to the `userDetailsService` provider; since no login had been entered, this would always result in a `BadCredentialsException`, which would then turn up in the `ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler`.

The solution was:

- Creating a `IPNotTrustedException` which extends `DisabledException`
- Throwing `IPNotTrustedException` in my `CustomIPAddressAuthenticationProvider`
- Mapping `IPNotTrustedException` to the `/notValidIP` URL I wanted to get to.

Of course, not forgetting to set `/notValidIP` to be accessible without authentication. Works like a charm. :)